# Dynamically allocating memory for structures

Tags: c++, memory, structure

I'm trying to dynamically allocate a structure, and need to know if I'm doing it right.  According to my book, I am.  But my compiler is giving me an error.  Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Declare structure
struct Airports{
    string name;
    string airID;
    double elevation;
    double runway;};

Airports *airptr;

airptr = new Airports[3];//This is where the error is happening
```

The compiler seems to think that airptr "has no storage class or type specifier."  I don't get how that can be seeing as I defined a structure and then defined airptr as a pointer to that structure.  Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance for any replys

Comment: Consider using `std::vector`. The error more suggests something like `airptr.name`.

Comment: I would like to, but for my assignment I have to use an array >_<

Comment: Here everything compiles fine with mingw 4.6. Can you post all errors outputted by the compiler? there might be something else going on

Comment: wild guess, you didn't put `airptr = new Airports[3];` in main()

Comment: @billz, Ooh, good thinking. That's probably it.

Comment: I'll try that.  As for my compiler errors, Visual Studio gives me the following on line 16 of the code:

 IntelliSense: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
Error 1 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Error 3 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Airports *' to 'int'

Error 2 error C2040: 'airptr' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'Airports *'

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that is wasn't defined in main....thanks all.  I'll prolly have some other silly problem later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm writing this, the presented code in the question is …

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Declare structure
struct Airports{
    string name;
    string airID;
    double elevation;
    double runway;};

Airports *airptr;

airptr = new Airports[3];//This is where the error is happening
```

With a non-declaration statement outside a function the compiler tries to interpret it as a declaration, but fails.

Put that in a `main` function.

---

Also, by using `std::vector` instead of raw arrays, pointers and `new`, you would avoid a lot of errors and painful work.